# How to remove circles from binary image but keep lines?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In the following image, how does one remove the circles in order to keep only the lines?

[image: http://s4.postimage.org/wndlnwph9/morph.png]

Comment: Instead of asking both in the same question, you should probably try to identify a good approach/algorithm first, then try the implementation in Matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a circular Hough transform to detect circles, and then you can delete them. The file exchange has several files you can use, for example [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26978-hough-transform-for-circles), or [this one](http://www.mathworks.us/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35223-circle-detection-using-hough-transforms). Matlab also offers a tool called [`imfindcircles`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html)  that does the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Do a morphological opening with an adequate structuring element:

[image]

`Opening[f, DiskMatrix[7]]`

To do the entire task there are a couple of approaches, some starting by subtracting the input image from the previous result (which you might experiment), as well distinct ones. One of these distinct ones start by thinning the input image, which reduces the circles -- that are not overlapping with lines -- to single pixels (or close to that, given the circles are not perfect) which you can remove easily. Then you prune this image and detect lines (following image at right).

[image] [image]

```
f = ImageCrop[Binarize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/AurlZ.png"]]] (* Input *)
g = SelectComponents[Thinning[f], "Count", #1 > 10 &]          (* Second image *)
h = Pruning[g, 9];
lines = ImageLines[h, 0.1, Method -> "RANSAC", Segmented -> True];
Show[Dilation[h, 3], Graphics[{Thick, Red, Line /@ lines}]]    (* Third image *)
```

You can try complementing the red lines in a given connected component by considering the detected circles in the first image shown together with the orientation of the segments that are close to a given circle.

Comment: Thank you
But I want to stay in line. And circles are removed

Comment: Sure, just remove this resulting image from the original one and do some smart line filling. At some point I might add something in this regard.